# What happens when a stock gets delisted?

Tags: india, stock-exchanges

Recently, a stock on the Indian stock exchange began rising on large volume without any apparent reason.  After 5 consecutive days of such growth, several people on a financial management site commented that "soon this stock will be delisted and money will be double" or something.

I know only one thing about delisting: if a stock is delisted, then we cannot trade on it.  So how can the stock double in value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a delisting happens, the primary process involves, the firm or the entity, trying to buy everyone out so that they can take the firm private by delisting from the stock exchanges. As the firm wants to buy everyone out, the current owners of the equity have the upper hand. They wouldn't want to sell if they believe the firm has a brighter future. So to compensate the existing holders, the buyer needs to compensate the current holders of any future loss, so they pay a premium to buy them out. Hence the prices offered will be more than the current existing price. And in anticipation of a premium the stocks price rises on this speculation.

The other scenario is if the current holder(s) decide no to sell their holdings and are small in number, dependent on exchange regulations, and the buyer manages to de-list the stock, the holders might loose out i.e. they have to find another buyer who wants to buy which becomes difficult as the liquidity for the stock is very minimal.

> if any stock is DE-listed and then we can not trade on it,

In India if the promoters capital is more than 90%, he can get the stock de-listed. There is a process, he has to make an open offer at specified price to minority shareholders. The minority shareholder can refuse to sell. Once the stock is de-listed, it means it cannot be traded on a given exchange. However you can still sell / buy by directly finding a buyer / seller and it's difficult compared to a listed stock.